# ALSA Linux based sound file and sound level detection

Tags: linux, audio, wav, alsa

Our are looking for a way to develop an automated system for our ALSA/Linux based product to test our codex card automatically. For this we envision the following steps:
1.  Play an existing known wave file
2.  Record sound from the MIC.
3.  If both speaker and MIC are working fine (as they are placed close to each other) the recorded file should have some version of the played sound
4.  Automatically analyse if the recorded file has some version of sound file.

Question: Is there an API, which can help analyse the recorded to find sound level or other parameters to help detect that both MIC and speaker in proximity are working fine.

Comment: ALSA gives you just the recorded samples; what you do with them is your own problem. You probably want to do an FFT.

Comment: alsamixer and amixer and two alsa utilities which have the ability to provide sound levels provided by arecord.

Comment: aplay has an option -v. if used 3 times aplay -v -v -v wave.wav, it starts a  VU-meter which provides the level of sound. Look for VU-meter in https://fossies.org/dox/alsa-utils-1.0.29/aplay_8c_source.html (aplay source code). This would become a starting point to detect level of sound in a sound file.